# Why is my NIKON AF-S 18-105 VR on my NIKON D5500 not autofocusing?

Tags: nikon, autofocus, af-s

When I acquired my camera, my 35 mm AF-s lens clearly worked as did my 18-55 lens. I am not sure a recently acquired 18-105 AF-s lens works. How can I check?

Simple replies please as I am clueless. I thought the lens would move as AF kicked in but I can see no sign of this.

Comment: Are the photos you take with the 18-105 lens in focus?

Comment: Michael - Thanks for that - In the main that would appear to occur,  however the fact that it does not always occur made me seek advice,   Thanks again - I will keep a close watch on future photos.   Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your AF-S 18-105 VR lens has what is known as *internal focusing*. That means that all of the movement when the lens focuses is on the inside of the lens and nothing on the outside of the lens moves when the lens autofocuses.

Your 18-55mm lens does not have an internal focus design and the front element and front barrel of the lens do move when the focus is changed on the lens.

Current versions of the Nikon 35mm AF-S primes have internal focusing (35mm f/1.8G AF-S DX, 35mm f/1.4G AF-S, 35mm f/1.8G AF-S). Other 35mm Nikon lenses (35mm f/2D AF) and possibly older 35mm AF-S lenses do not.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed for such a concise answer which has improved my knowledge 100%.   I shall now practice more and not imagine problems that do not exist.   Thanks again.